# Error while trying to connect with js code and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ecmascript-6, postman

So I've been trying to figure this error and I couldn't find any solution everywhere.
After sometime I know where the problem is but I don't know why:

```
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
```

I believe that here is the problem because it keeps catching the consol.log("not working")

This is my code:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save(); //I believe here is the problem
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("not working");
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

and I'm using postman I put the boy as raw and Json:

```
{
    "username":"lama",
    "email":"lama@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345"

}
```

and for some reason I get this as a result:

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 8000,
    "codeName": "AtlasError"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to MongoDB Atlas: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097612/connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-com-mongodb-mongocommandexception-command-failed-w)

Comment: not really as my problem is after connecting it catches the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666655/command-failed-with-error-8000-atlaserror-when-try-to-insert-data-into-collect

Comment: I think I found where the problem is but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: @omerbt Can you post your database connection code?

Comment: @lpizzinidev do you mean: mongodb+srv://ecommerce:<password>@cluster0.9rvbret.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: okay I solved the problem the solution is to give access to everything from mongodb database :)